Visual Studio 2022 has no way to create a markdown (.md) file
I'm not sure if I'm going nuts here, but I see no templates under "Add New Item" to create a .md file.  I'm completely shocked by this.  Does anyone know why this is the case?
I know I could create a text file then rename it, but does anyone know how to set up VS 2022 to have this as an option?  Seems really stupid that it's not an option.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/write-markdown-without-leaving-visual-studio/

After I installed the Visual Studio 2022 preview and tested it with related extensions, I found that there is really no way to have an option to directly create a template for .md files under "Add New Item". The only way at the moment is to rename it. If you really want the option to directly create a template for .md files under "Add New Item", I suggest you report this feature request to DC, there are more VS developers on DC, and they may be able to help you:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.
